# How to logout an ssh session from within a perl script?

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, debian

I have a perl script to do a second layer of authentication after an ssh shell is opened. It asks for password, and after n number of invalid attempts, the script should log out the user. This runs on a Debian system.

Now, the problem is that usually an ssh shell is closed interactively with the command `exit`.

When run from backticks, or system() from within a perl script, `exit` is not recognized as a valid command. So how can I logout the user from an ssh session, from within a perl script? The script is not responsible for the ssh session. It runs on the remote, and kicks in from .bashrc.

This is the relevant segment of code:

```
while ($actualpass ne $password) {
    ++$attempts;
    if ( $attempts > $maxattempts ) {
        `/bin/bash /root/ascii_breach`;
        `/bin/bash exit`;
    }
```

The `/bin/bash exit` obviously does not work.

Comment: A hack to send signal to parent (shell PID) `perl -e 'kill HUP => getppid()'`

Comment: @mpapec That was just awesome. Exactly what I wanted without needing to edit system files. Make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have this a bit backwards.  I think what you are doing is ssh'ing to the remote host which runs a shell, the shell runs perl and then perl wants to exit the shell.  The better way of doing this is to ssh to the host to run the perl script directly.  Only if the authentication passes should the perl script start up the shell.

You can configure sshd to run your authentication script in the authorized_keys file assuming that is how the user is getting in.

Comment: This was supposed to be a double layer of authentication. sshd runs pam authentication. User thinks he gets in, but the perl script is initiated. If that layer fails, user needs to get in via pam again.

Comment: Sure.  My comment stands - your authentication process should start the actual shell on success not try to exit the one that started it on failure.

Comment: Doesnt authorized_keys just store acceptable public keys?

Comment: It can also configure the commands for a user.  There are various possible solutions here - the key is that on connection, the auth script is run, not the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You could launch the authentication script, check the exit status and logout the shell on failure:

```
perl auth.pl; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit; fi
```

Then in the Perl script:

```
if ( $attempts > $maxattempts ) {
    die 'Authentication failed';
}
```

You would also need to stop the user skipping the authentication with ctrl+c or ctrl+z:

```
trap "echo no" SIGINT SIGTSTP
perl auth.pl; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit; fi
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, exit within a bash script just stops that program.